# implement footer in ui5 shell

Tags: sapui5

i've a shell implemented in sap.ui.view (sapui5) desktop top application view. now i've a requirement to add a footer to the view. there are ways to add footer for sap.ui.m but i dont see anyways to implement the same in views while shell being the default content. i've added another div after the default content, it stays behind the default ones but not at the bottom.

any pointers on how to implement the footer for ui5 desktop views while shell is the default view.

tnx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the ux3.Shell, that is a problem. It is designed as the top Element in an application. Short of using an iframe around it (which would be plain ugly), I suppose the only way is to put the footer inside the shell content.

Comment: will give a try as suggested by you. but i've also tried using below: 
1. adding another div tag <div id=footer></div> after content tag
2. adding layouts, text/lable elements after </ux3:shell> tag

both resulted behind the headerItems of shell. now putting inside it.. how can we push it down to the bottom?
if i add padding, margine or <br> it will move down.. but its not a fixed position.. there must be some way to do it!

Comment: How about CSS position: fixed or absolute and bottom: 0? If you need to use a control,  try the layout/Splitter and set the lower content area's layout data's resizable-property to false

Comment: i've proposed the links on the footer to the tool/header area of shell..! anyways thanks for ur inputs.. its was worth trying those options.